# What do the --frontend and --mode options for do-release-upgrade do?

Tags: do-release-upgrade

From the [`do-release-upgrade` manual](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/do-release-upgrade.8.html):

```
       -m MODE, --mode=MODE
              Run in a special upgrade mode. Currently "desktop" for regular upgrades of
              a desktop system and "server" for server systems are supported.
```

That's fairly useless documentation. What do these modes mean? What is "special" about either of them? What is the default, and does it relate in any way to whether we're running Ubuntu Server or Ubuntu Desktop edition?

```
       -f FRONTEND, --frontend=FRONTEND
              Run the specified frontend
```

That's even less helpful. What's a frontend? What frontends are available, and how do they differ?

Comment: The link inside my answer also explains `--mode`

Comment: Thank you. I somehow didn't find that question.

Comment: No problem! I also found it only because I remembered having answered it just a few weeks ago and had it in my profile ;-)

Comment: Wondered how often this `--frontend` option is used ... and why use `gui` through commands - or did I understand wrong the idea?